# String capture function giving unknown error

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

df71 equals:

```
                                            PIC_1  p_lgth  Wgt
                   420294189300189843900787520557      30  112
                   420951119300189843900787520618      30   64
**PARTIAL-DECODE***P / 42011721930018984390078...      53  112
                   420112289300189843900782713107      30  144
                   420212369300189843900787520397      30   70
```

Below is the function I'm applying to each row of df71 using apply()

```
def pic_mod(row):
 if row['p_lgth'] !=30:
    n = row['PIC_1'].str.find('42')
    PIC_2 = row['PIC_1'].str[int(n):int(n+28)]
 elif row['p_lgth']==30:
    PIC_2=row['PIC_1']  
 return PIC_2


df71['PIC_1_master'] = df71.apply(pic_mod, axis=1)
```

When I run the above code, I get:

```
File "<ipython-input-192-9d112a2f0924>", line 3, in pic_mod
  n = row['PIC_1'].str.find('42')

AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at 
index   2')
```

Why!!!???? Below are the data types in case you're wondering.

```
df71.dtypes

PIC_1     object
p_lgth     int64
Wgt       object
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `row['PIC_1]'` is already a string. You just need to do `row['PIC_1'].find`

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row['PIC_1']` is already `str`. You are trying to get an attribute `str` from an already `str` type, which is why it's complaining.

Instead change it to `row['PIC_1'].find('42)`

In the future if you have something that is not `str`, you would not try to access an attribute either, but instead do `str(112233445542)` to convert it to `str`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `pd.DataFrame.apply`, a series-like object is passed to a function, where components can be extracted via syntax `row['col']`.

Now `row['col']` will represent an element of your series, so it is likely a scalar such as `str` or `int` or `float`. If it is a string, it will not have a `str` accessor like a `pd.Series` object.

Therefore, remove all instances of `str` attributes in `pic_mod`:

- Replace `row['PIC_1'].str.find('42')` with `row['PIC_1'].find('42')`.
- Replace `row['PIC_1'].str[int(n):int(n+28)]` with `row['PIC_1'][int(n):int(n+28)]`.